# incremental number using jQuery .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

How do I increment up to a specific number (3), then have it reset, looping back to the first number. The first number should begin at 1 (not 0).

I've tried using: `i=1; i<=3; i+=1`

Here's my basic code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".std-price .local-pricing").each(function(i) {
            $(this).addClass("ab-price" + (i));
    });
});
```

If I used `for()` or `each()`, it would then give me `class="ab-price1 ab-price2 ab-price3"`

Any help and reference links (to learn in the process) would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you simply looking for i%3 ?

Comment: if you need the # to be dynamic, you could also substitute 3 with `$(".std-price .local-pricing").length||0`. Or instead of a mod, just use `if (i==0) { i = 1 }` at the top of your function.

Comment: @dystroy - Yes, exactly what I was looking for. Is there some documentation you can link to? Thanks!

Comment: @MikelWard There's [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set the classes `ab-price1, ab-price2, ab-price3, ab-price1, ab-price2`, etc. then you can do this :

```
$(".std-price .local-pricing").each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass("ab-price" + (1+(i%3)));
});
```

This uses [the modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators).

If you don't need to be compatible with IE8, this could also be solved in pure CSS using the [:nth-of-type() pseudo class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation):

```
$(".std-price .local-pricing").addClass(function(i) {
    return "ab-price" + (i % 3 + 1);
});
```

Also, quite a few jQuery functions take callbacks (e.g. `addClass`, `width`, `attr`, and `prop`), so you can usually get rid of `each`.